# React Native Expo App crashes in Production mode

Tags: react-native, expo

My app crashes when I start to run it in production mode. In dev mode all works correctly. Only logs I have on the screen. What can I do?

I used:
"expo": "38.0.10",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-native": "~0.62.2",

[Link to screenshot with logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKyEq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. It's all because of wrong auto import.

I have imported useState from "react/cjs/react.development", not from 'react'.

Instead

`import { useState } from "react/cjs/react.development";`

I need write

`import React, { useState } from "react";`